# DRBD device fails timed out at Server boot time

Tags: debian, boot, drbd

Restarting my server get stalled , apparently because of the only one error I see with journalctl -xb

```
...
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
may 22 11:21:56 node01.urbina.biz kernel: random: crng init done
may 22 11:22:36 node01.urbina.biz systemd[1]: dev-drbd1.device: Job dev-drbd1.device/start timed ou
may 22 11:22:36 node01.urbina.biz systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-drbd1.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-drbd1.device has faile
...
```

However, when I enter the emergency system ("Enter root password or hit Ctrl-D to continue)  I see that the module drbd is loaded, but for some reason, my /dev/drbd1 device times out :( :( :(

Comment: How is DRBD configured? Are you setting a wfc-timeout? Is the device's peer up and reachable?

Comment: Sure:  1.- peer is reachable (indeed resyncing every manual reboot I've been doing lately) 2.- wfc-timeout  15;  However, boot log shows ```may 22 11:21:06 node01.dom.biz systemd-modules-load[236]: Inserted module 'drbd'
may 22 11:22:36 node01.dom.biz systemd[1]: dev-drbd1.device: Job dev-drbd1.device/start timed ou
t.
may 22 11:22:36 node01.dom.biz systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-drbd1.device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-drbd1.device has failed
-- Unit dev-drbd1.device has failed.
may 22 11:22:36 node01.dom.biz systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/drbd1.```

Comment: Are you trying to Promote DRBD and mount it at boot? I don't really understand what, "my /dev/drbd1 device times out", means. Perhaps including the entire configuration would be better.

Answer (score 0):

kereczman, I answer in a new reply as I do not know how to publish readable code in a comment.

My only device setup:

```
resource r1 {
    protocol B;
    startup {
        wfc-timeout  15;
        degr-wfc-timeout 60;
    }
    net {
        cram-hmac-alg sha1;
        shared-secret "***********";
        max-buffers 4096;
        max-epoch-size 4096;
    }
    handlers {
        split-brain "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-split-brain.sh soporte@mydom.es";
    }

        on node01.urbina.biz {
                device /dev/drbd1;
                disk /dev/vdb1;
                address x.y.z.w:7799;
                meta-disk internal;
        }

        on failover.urbina-solutions.net {
                device /dev/drbd1;
                disk /dev/vdb1;
                address w.z.y.x:7799;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
}
```

And the error message is about unability to mount the drbd, as if the module was not already loaded, but it is.

Comment: Ok, allow me to add more info as I investigate ::  drbd device formatted as xfs. Both needed modules, drbd and xfs properly loaded. However ```journal -xb```shows **"dev-drbd1.device: Job dev-drbd1.device/start failed with result 'timeout'"**  And all I can see is **"Dependency failed for /mnt/drbd1"** but no detail at all about such dependency, nor in var/log/messages neither in var/log/syslog. Where does Drbd log otherwise?